How to access the API from Fresh frontend within Docker containers?
I'm using Docker Compose (V2) to start up a mostly stock Deno Fresh frontend and a stock FastAPI backend.
According to what I've read, since Compose creates a network that includes both containers (which I've verified), in the frontend I should be able to access the API with either:
http://api:5000/
or simply
api:5000/
But both http://api:5000/ and http://localhost:5000/ throw ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and /api:5000/ returns a 404 Not Found.
If I use http://[server]:5000/ in my Fresh component, then it gets data from the API, but I don't want to hardcode the server name in the component since that may change or be unknown.
Given this compose file, what am I doing wrong?
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./fast-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.fastapi
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.fresh
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

Fresh component
import { useEffect, useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function ApiFetch()  {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://api:5000/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello from {data ? data.Hello : "still loading..."}</div>;
};

I saw some samples of this use case that used react and some other API for the backend, and that used some kind of proxy setup in package.json, but that doesn't exist in Fresh, so I'm not sure if I need some kind of proxy setting like that or not; I couldn't find any Deno/Fresh documentation on that.

Please [edit] your question to show the code making the API requests. Are they being made directly by the browser or is it server side data fetching?

Have you also verified your API is actually running? Can you make a request with curl / Postman to http://localhost:5000?

Yes, I can access http://[server]:5000/ from the browser, and if I use that in my Fresh component as well, then it gets data from the API, but I don't want to hardcode the server name in the component since that may change or be unknown.

Sorry, what is [server]? When run from the browser you would use localhost. When run from the Fresh server, you would use api. As for hard-coding URLs, check the Fresh docs for environment configuration

Since your request is made from the browser (useEffect runs client-side) use localhost. See: Fail to resolve docker compose service name from front end

Looks like env based configuration for client-side code isn't great in Fresh ~ https://github.com/denoland/fresh/issues/2427

It appears that — in your Docker environment — the scheme and domain of your client and server are the same, and that they only differ by port number. If this relationship will continue after deployment, then you can dynamically construct the URL in your client JavaScript code like this:


/* Use `window.location.href` in your client app…
 * but because this is running on Stack Overflow and not your app,
 * I'll provide a hardcoded substitute for the demo: */

function getServerUrl(port = 5000) {
  // const windowUrl = window.location.href;
  const windowUrl = "http://my.site:8000/some_view.html";
  const { hostname, protocol } = new URL(windowUrl);
  return new URL(`${protocol}//${hostname}:${port}/`);
}

console.log(getServerUrl().href); // "http://my.site:5000/"



…and then use it in your code:
fetch(getServerUrl())

